# Where is "root_url" in Octopress?

Tags: jekyll, octopress

Maybe this is some kind of Jekyll setting or something but I need to set root_url to something other then "/" and I can't figure out where to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for asking too quickly.  You can find the settings in **_config.yml**.  I thought I checked there but I must have opened one of the other two config files twice.

Comment: It's the root: not root_url:.

Answer (score 3):

In the `.themes/classic/source/_layouts/default.html` file, there is `{% capture root_url %}{{ site.root | strip_slash }}{% endcapture %}`.

`site.root` is configured in `_config.yml` which defaults to `root: /`.

If you are testing with `http://127.0.0.1:4000/` which is the default settings for jekyll local development, you can change it to `root: http://127.0.0.1:4000/`. Then the path will be correct. For example, `<link href="{{ root_url }}/favicon.png" rel="icon">` will be resolved as `<link href="http://127.0.0.1:4000//favicon.png" rel="icon">`.

In short, changing the line `root: /` in the `_config.yml` will do.